# On using __attribute__((format(printf,

Tags: c++, gcc, attributes, format, clang

I'm trying to suppress -Wformat-nonliteral warnings.  I have used **attribute**((format(printf with success elsewhere but the following example eludes me.

exceptions.hpp

```
class Exceptions {
  ...

  static void fthrow(Thread* thread, const char* file, int line, Symbol* name,
                     const char* format, ...);
};
```

exceptions.cpp

```
__attribute__((format(printf, 5, 6)))
void Exceptions::fthrow(Thread* thread, const char* file, int line, Symbol* h_name, const char* format, ...) {
  const int max_msg_size = 1024;
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, format);
  char msg[max_msg_size];
  vsnprintf(msg, max_msg_size, format, ap);
  msg[max_msg_size-1] = '\0';
  va_end(ap);
  _throw_msg(thread, file, line, h_name, msg);
}
```

result

```
exceptions.cpp:229:16: error: format argument not a string type
__attribute__((format(printf, 5, 6)))
               ^              ~
exceptions.cpp:235:32: error: format string is not a string literal [-Werror,-Wformat-nonliteral]
  vsnprintf(msg, max_msg_size, format, ap);
                               ^~~~~~
```

Since it is a static, the exact index should be used, but I've tried 4, 5 and 6, 7 (if out by one) with similar fail.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute should be set on the declaration of the function, not the definition.

```
class Exceptions {
  ...

  static void fthrow(Thread* thread, const char* file, int line, Symbol* name,
                     const char* format, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 5, 6)));
};
```